# Save data from api request to db (JSON)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api, ruby-on-rails-4, get

I sending messages from my rail app through third party and track the deliver details and store it in my database table.After sending messages third party post deliver details to my given URL,I got response to my URL like.

```
http://yourdomain.com/dlr/pushUrl.php?data=%7B%22requestId%22%3A%22546b384ce51f469a2e8b4567%22%2C%22numbers%22%3A%7B%22911234567890%22%3A%7B%22date%22%3A%222014-11-18+17%3A45%3A59%22%2C%22status%22%3A1%2C%22desc%22%3A%22DELIVERED%22%7D%7D%7D
```

Like following format,

```
data={

  "requestId":"546b384ce51f469a2e8b4567",

  "numbers":{

    "911234567890":{

      "date":"2014-11-18 17:45:59",

      "status":1,

      "desc":"DELIVERED"

}}}
```

I used following code in my controller to display data.

```
json = params["data"]["numbers"]
puts json
```

But it displays NULL. Now I want to save the data into database.Is there any Gem to be used or any other method is good.Am new to ROR.

Comment: Am I understanding correctly? `params['data']` returns what you wrote and `params['data']['numbers']` returns `NIL`?

Comment: params['data'] and params['data']['numbers'] both returns NIL only.

Comment: now throws 'no implicit conversion of nil into String' errors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is that `params["data"]` is a string, but you are treating it like a hash.

```
data = JSON.parse(params["data"])
puts data['numbers']
```

Comment: Its work fines. Now how to save requestId, numbers, date, desc in my table.? how to read?

Comment: How to save data to db automatically when response is hit my URL.